# Paypal Vault card number is masked

Tags: paypal, paypal-vault

In sandbox mode i am able to store credit card numbers, however when i retrieve it the card number is masked IE "xxxxxxxxxxxx1111".
The documentation states that it should be a numeric string.
Is this how it is supposed to work or does it just do this in the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct functionality. The full card number is hidden in the response, so the above information is accurate.

You'll find the information in the developer's page under Vaulted Credit Cards: 
"The credit card number. Valid value is a string of numeric characters with no spaces or punctuation. Must conform to modulo and the length required by its credit card type. *Redacted in responses*."

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/vault/#credit-card_create_response